# SQL-Server Transaction Blocking Mystery

Tags: stored-procedures, sql-server-2012, transactions, blocking

I have a .Net app used for form processing which deletes/updates/inserts data across three different SQL Server 2012 databases. When the application runs, it opens a data context and then a transaction within that context for each form that needs to be processed (this runs every minute, so it's usually no more than one form at a time). A bunch of stuff happens within this transaction -- including multiple stored proc calls.

So here's the problem:

We have servers set up with what I'm told are the exact same specs (although I'm dubious :)). One is used for development work; the other for client testing. In our development environment, the processing runs without problems; but on the client testing site, it hangs every time. And I'm pulling my hair out trying to determine why.

In the following TSQL code, it is the insert into the Param table that is failing. The Param table is essentially the same as the Method table, except for the column names. Both inserts have similar foreign key relationships to the Form table, and both insert int values into the ID column.

When I run SQL Server Profiler, I'm told there's a lock on the FormDB which is not allowing the insert. However, I can alter the select statement for the Param insert and it works. I've altered in the following ways, all of which "work" in the sense that they do not cause the blocking issue:

- Replaced the Param select with the Method select while keeping the insert to Param.(exact same column defs as param select)
- Replaced @newKey with a valid integer for an existing form.
- Removed the "from" portion of the Param select and hardcoded a single int value for the paramID (ie select @newKey, 1, @modifyDate, @modifyUser)

I feel like I'm losing my mind, because I just can't see why it's not working. The insert only seems to fail when three things are all in the select statement in combination -- @newKey, ParamID, and the from statement.

I've ensured each sproc has SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED and have used with nolock where necessary.

Why can I successfully insert into the Param table via the three scenarios above, but fail for the Param insert in the code that follows? Why would I not receive the same lock message in the profiler? There are about 5 other inserts in this procedure which follow the same pattern. All of them work with no problem.

Any ideas? Thanks.

```
USE [PROD]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[HELPSPROC]
    @oldKey int 
AS

BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    SET TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL READ UNCOMMITTED;

    declare @newKey int
    , @spKey int
    , @modifyDate datetime = getdate()
    , @modifyUser varchar(30) = 'User'

/*
a bunch of stuff happens here, including setting the @spKey value. 
this all happening correctly -- we have a valid integer value when we go into the next part
*/

---------------FORM---------------
INSERT INTO FormDB.dbo.Form
    (formtype, formstatus, modifydate, modifyuser)
Select 
    'TestFormType', 'DRAFT', @modifyDate, @modifyUser                            
From FormDB2.dbo.Form f  
Where f.Pkey = @oldKey

--grab the new int identifier -- works                     
set @newKey = (select scope_identity())

/*
stuff happens here. all is good in this part
*/


---------------Param---------------
INSERT INTO  FormDB.dbo.Param
    (FormKey, ParamID, ModifyDate, ModifyUser) 
select @newKey, p.ParamID, @modifyDate, @modifyUser
from PROD.dbo.Table1 apd 
    inner join PROD.dbo.ParameterTable p 
        on apd.TableTwoKey = p.TableTwoKey
where apd.PKey = @spKey



---------------Method---------------
INSERT INTO  FormDB.dbo.Method
    (FormKey, MethodID, ModifyDate, ModifyUser) 
select @newKey, r.MethodID, @modifyDate, @modifyUser
from PROD.dbo.Table1 apd 
    inner join PROD.dbo.MethodTable r 
        on apd.TableTwoKey = r.TableTwoKey
where apd.PKey = @spKey

/*
one more insert ...
*/


RETURN 1

END

GO
```

Comment: What do you mean by "there's a lock on the FormDB"?

Comment: Hi @Alex. From the details I obtained using SQL Profiler, the Activity Monitor, and the following sproc from [Microsoft](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/271509/how-to-monitor-blocking-in-sql-server-2005-and-in-sql-server-2000), I could see that one SPID -- with status sleeping, and awaiting command --  was blocking the current insert on another SPID (status suspended).

Answer (score 0):

I still don't understand the *why* of this problem, but I found a solution.

There are a lot of things happening in the vb.net code for this process: multiple linq-to-sql inserts/deletes/updates across three separate databases, as well as two separate stored procedures calls. To add to that confusion, there are separate contexts declared for each db, each with its own transaction. In short, a bunch of moving parts.

The second stored proc call was conditional, based on certain values for the processing form. I just took that call out of the vb.net code, and placed the conditional logic and stored proc call within the first proc. That solved it. The second stored proc was called directly after the first anyway -- pending conditions -- so all is good.

Problem solved -- but if anybody can explain why this was occurring, I'd be grateful. Thanks!

Comment: My guess: You probably have uncommitted transaction somewhere. If you use Linked servers check that "Enable Promotion of Distributed Transactions" settings are the same.

Comment: Great. Thanks for the tip @Alex!